# jQuery append to a ul without an id?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, append, squarespace

I've been working on a squarespace site (which does not let you edit the body code or this would be as easy as dropping another **li** item into a **ul**) and I need to pin the squarespace block for social icons into the navbar (which is structured as a **ul**). All the jQuery tuts I've seen on appending use the **ul-id** as the point to append *to*. Unfortunately, the **ul** on my site does not have a specific id. It looks like this:

```
<header id="header" data-content-field="page-settings">
   <div id="topNav">
     <nav class="main-nav dropdown-hover desktop-nav">
       <ul>
        <li class="page-collection active-link" id="51f05bd9e4b01bb187e35cd7
          <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
   </div>
</header>
```

Now I want to append the following code to this list (keep in mind this is a "block" of squarespace code that the site reads in a way that displays social media icons where it is placed.)

```
   <li class="social-links">
      <a href="youtube link" target="_blank" class="social-youtube"></a>
      <a href="facebook link" target="_blank" class="social-facebook"></a>
      <a href="twitter link" target="_blank" class="social-twitter"></a>
      <a href="instagram link" target="_blank" class="social-instagram"></a>
    </li>
```

Is it possible to append to the existing **ul** in the header using the jQuery .append() function? If so what class/id do I append *to*?

Answer (score 1):

You can select it hierarchally:

```
var html = '<li><!-- etc --></li>';

$('#topnav .main-nav > ul').append(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
$('div#topnav nav.main-nav > ul').append('li html code here');
```